# SQL only a throw inside if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, throw

I am adding some validation to a couple of stored procedures and need to check if some of the variables are not null (they are populated earlier in the stored procedure).

I have been trying to add a "throw" inside an if statement like below:

```
IF (@val is null)
BEGIN
    THROW 50001, 'Custom text', 1
END
```

This causes a syntax error on the "throw" as it is looking for other code inside the if statement prior to the throw but I only need it to perform the throw inside the if statement.

I need to keep the stored procedure as light as possible to keep it as fast as possible to execute.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: [THROW is a SQL Server 2012 feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670985/i-am-unable-to-use-throw-sql-server-2008-r2)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The syntax error is showing up because the previous statement hasn't been terminated. The other answers will work, but in order to do it this way you can either throw a semicolon right before the THROW, or get in the habit of terminating all statements with semicolons.

```
IF (@val is null)
BEGIN
    ;THROW 50001, 'Custom text', 1
END
```

or

```
IF (@val is null)
BEGIN;
    THROW 50001, 'Custom text', 1;
END;
```

You may have noticed that:

```
IF (@val is null)
    THROW 50001, 'Custom text', 1
```

... will also work, and this is because SQL Server knows that the next thing to come after an IF statement is always a new T-SQL statement.

It is perhaps worth noting that Microsoft has stated that the T-SQL language in the future will require semicolons after each statement, so my recommendation would be to start building the habit now.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: That syntax surely looks weird BEGIN; statements here END; Why is it OK to terminate the BEGIN !?

Comment: @joedotnot Blame Microsoft maybe? :-) Perhaps when the throw is the only statement, omitting BEGIN/END is preferable, and when some other statement is used before the throw, the semicolon after BEGIN is unnecessary.

Comment: Similar to the WITH statement to create a Common Table Expression : the previous statement also needs to be terminated for WITH to work :P

Comment: Apparently, it thinks `END TRY BEGIN CATCH` is a single statement. It won't allow a semicolon after `END TRY`, and displays an error "expecting END CATCH". But you can terminate the whole thing as `END TRY BEGIN CATCH;`

Answer (score 3):

If this is for SQL Server, the intellisense syntax highlighter doesn't like it, but the code should compile and run fine. Of course, with it being a single statement, you don't need the `BEGIN`...`END` block at all:

```
IF (@val is null) THROW 50001, 'Custom text', 1
```

Comment: I still get "incorrect syntax near throw" when building with readyroll (it compiles and works correct in ssms.

Answer (score -2):

```
DECLARE @val NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
IF @val is null

    RAISERROR('Custom text', 16,16)
```

for different level
check

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx

Comment: Looks like the readyroll software does not like throw and gives an error when compiling but using RAISERROR works correctly.

Comment: RAISERROR should no longer be used in new code, since it will be discontinued in the future.

Comment: @NReilingh Its 2019 ending but still we are using RAISERROR